# Where to define a jQuery $.ajax() success function if you don't want to define in the call to $.ajax()?

Tags: jquery

If I want to separate out my ajax `success` function so that it is defined elsewhere in my `<script>`, does it have to be inside the

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
```

section or could it be defined along with non-jQuery javascript functions?

```
  $.ajax(
  {
    url: '/load_prayer',
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    data: ({ 'prayerId' : prayerId }),
    success: function(data)
    {
        $('#prayer_date').html(data.Date);
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(e, xhr)
    {
        console.log(e);
    }
  });
```

The reason I don't want to define it inside the call to `ajax` is it will eventually be a large function and it will be confusing to read if it's mixed in with the other `ajax` call parameters.

For example, would this work:

```
$.ajax(
{
    url: '/load_prayer',
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    data: ({ 'prayerId' : prayerId }),
    success: handlePrayer(data),
    error: function(e, xhr)
    {
        console.log(e);
    }
});

handlePrayer(data)
{
    $('#prayer_date').html(data.Date);
    console.log(data);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You have to change it so its only the function name. Like so:

```
$.ajax(
{
    url: '/load_prayer',
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    data: ({ 'prayerId' : prayerId }),
    success: handlePrayer,
    error: function(e, xhr)
    {
        console.log(e);
    }
});
```

And you need put function where you declare it like so

```
function handlePrayer(data)
{
    $('#prayer_date').html(data.Date);
    console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: @Ken, if any of these solved your problem then please do accept one of them :)

Answer (score 4):

As long as the function has been loaded before $.ajax is called, it should work. That means it *can* be outside `$(document).ready(...)`.

**With one exception**: All variables that need to be accessed need to be outside that success function. The below `ajaxCallWorked()` function would be able to access `outside` but not `inside`.

```
var outside;

function ajaxCallWorked(data) {
    ...
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var inside;
    $.ajax({
        ...
        success: ajaxCallWorked,
        ...
    });
}
```

Comment: For pointing out that 'ajaxCallWorked' is just an expression for a function-object (just as a function-expression is...) :-) It's all explained here: http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/ (somewhere)

Comment: So, if `ajaxCallWorked` is defined inside `$(document).ready(...)`, it can access inside and the `$.ajax()` call can also access it?

Answer (score 0):

i believe you can define the function outside the scope of both the ajax call and the onready.