# Correct way to wait for ajax to return (I don't want to use the success handler.)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get jQuery to perform a synchronous, rather than asynchronous, AJAX request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133310/how-can-i-get-jquery-to-perform-a-synchronous-rather-than-asynchronous-ajax-re)
>   [how to wait for an ajax call to return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387852/how-to-wait-for-an-ajax-call-to-return)

Hear me out.  I completely understand this code segment.

```
$.getJSON(someURL, function(data){
    //do something with my data
})
.success(function () {
    //Call what you want on success
})
```

This seems fine if I just need to take one action that is pretty static.  However, what if I want to be less restricted, for instance this

```
function my_func(){
    $.getJSON(someURL, function(data){
        //do something with my data... like modify an array or the dom
    })
}
```

Now the driver

```
my_func();
//Now I want to call a function that relies on the data that my_func brought into the script.
```

Is there something wrong with the way I'm coding my script if I want to do it like this?  Or am I just missing some awesome built in method?

Comment: But that is what the success callback is for...any particular reason why it would not work for you? In what way do you need to be less restricted?

Comment: "Or am I just missing some awesome built in method?" Yup: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ with `async: false`

Comment: Your page will appear to suck and act like it's locking up.  Any idea why you are seeking this "feature"?

Comment: Or: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010816/where-to-define-a-jquery-ajax-success-function-if-you-dont-want-to-define-i And many many others

Comment: My javascript just looks like an unruly mess and I thought that this was one more thing I could refactor to clean it up.  I read some of the other similar questions but everyone seemed so gung ho on the success callback and I specifically wanted to know what other options were out there

Comment: I'll give a for instance.  My json request is getting the list of all users in the database and modifying a global array of User objects.  When it is done modifying the users I want to update the users list in the dom.  Should I just write a function modify_dom and call it as the callback?  Is the the 'correct' way to do it?  What if I have two ajax requests that go out.. one for users and one for notes users have written and I want to draw a table of the table once both requests have finished? Do I cal 1 ajax request as a callback from the other and then call modify_dom in the other callback?

Comment: And just for argument's sake: IF indeed a .success callback CAN become more complex, is there a complexity (and what is it) at which it would be irresponsible NOT to do it differently?

Comment: @Jake: if your source looks a mess due to anonymous functions, you can always define them as named functions (in closures, to avoid polluting the global namespace) so they don't have to be placed inline in the asynchronous function call.

Comment: @Jake, making your calls synchronous (no callbacks) is with almost no exception a terrible idea.  You should categorically not be going down this road to "clean up your code."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I see two possible jQuery-ish ways there.

The first would be to use another callback that can be passed to `my_func`:

```
function my_func(callback) {
    $.getJSON(someUrl, function(data) {
        // ...do stuff ...
        if ($.isFunction(callback)) { callback(data); }
    });
}

my_func(function(data) {
    // ..do more stuff..
});
```

The second way would be to create a custom event that gets triggered inside `my_func` and can be listened to from the outside:

```
function my_func() {
    $.getJSON(someUrl, function(data) {
        $(document).triggerHandler('my_func:data-received', [data]);
    });
}

$(document).on('my_func:data-received', function(event, data) {
    // ...do stuff...
});

my_func();
```

I strongly recommend using `async: false` only if it is absolutely necessary.

---

Just another (very neat) way to deal with this is the jQuery.Deferred object:

```
function my_func() {
    var d = new $.Deferred();
    $.getJSON(someUrl, function(data) {
        d.resolve(data);
    });
    return d;
}

my_func().done(function(data) {
    // ...do stuff...
});
```

Your function returns an object that allows to register callbacks. Within the function you then just need to make sure to call `resolve` to invoke all registered `done` callback handlers.

Comment: Deferred! I knew I had heard of something about that.  I think I heard a speech on the topic at last years jquery summit.. I should go find the recordings. Woohoo!

Answer (score 2):

Then there's the XHR object:

```
var jqXHR = $.getJSON(someURL);
```

You can access it anywhere after it is defined:

```
jqXHR.always(function() {
    alert('JSON IS COMLETE');
});

jqXHR.done(function(data) {
    //do something with the returned data if success!
});

jqXHR.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    alert('JSON FAILED : '+textStatus);
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/jxZck/)

You could even do something like this:

```
$("#button").on('click', Myfunc);

function Myfunc() {
    var jqXHR = runAjax();
        jqXHR.done(function(data) {
            alert($.parseJSON(data));
            $("#result").html('JSON IS DONE');
        });
}

function runAjax() {
    return $.getJSON(someURL);
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/jxZck/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably pass your function that runs on the data to `my_func()`.

```
 //                    v--------receive a callback
function my_func(callback_fn){

    $.getJSON(someURL, callback_fn); // use the callback as the getJSON callback

}
```

then...

```
my_func(function(data) {
    // do something with data
})
```

...or if the function you wanted to call was a named function, then of course you'd pass it by name...

```
my_func(someOtherFunction)
```

Either way, your `my_func()` function will use it as the callback to the `$.getJSON` call, which will invoke it when the data arrives.

Comment: You know it's an exact dupe of a dupe of a dupe right?

Comment: @PeeHaa: Sure. Nearly everything is a dupe.

Comment: Yup that's why we have the close as exact dupe option.

Comment: @PeeHaa: We should just shut down StackOverflow *(as in freeze in current state)*. There's plenty of information here to answer 99% of questions. Fact is that dupes are rarely closed, so I've given up.

Comment: @PeeHaa: If you were concerned that I'm rep-whoring... don't be. I don't care about rep. If you can find a way for me to easily transfer most of mine to you, I'd be happy to do it. *(Just want to keep enough to avoid the ads, and be able to vote and comment and such.)*